# BigO of Algorithm Using Multiple Variable Regression

Tags: r, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, multiple-regression

For more verbose algorithms, determining the time complexity (i.e. BigO) is a pain. My solution has been to time the execution of the algorithm with parameters n and k, and come up with a function (time function) that varies with n and k.

My data looks something like the below:

```
n    k    executionTime
500  1    0.02
500  2    0.03
500  3    0.05
500  ...  ...
500  10   0.18
1000 1    0.08
...  ... ...
10000 1   9.8
...  ...  ...
10000 10  74.57
```

I've been using the lm() function in the stats R package. I don't know how to interpret the output of the multiple regression, to determine a final Big-O. **This is my main question: how do you translate the output of a multiple variable regression, to a final ruling on the best Big-O time complexity rating?**

Here's the output of the lm():

```
Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-14.943  -5.325  -1.916   3.681  31.475 

Coefficients:
          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -2.130e+01  1.591e+00  -13.39   <2e-16 ***
n            4.080e-03  1.953e-04   20.89   <2e-16 ***
k            2.361e+00  1.960e-01   12.05   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 7.962 on 197 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.747, Adjusted R-squared:  0.7444 
F-statistic: 290.8 on 2 and 197 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Here's the output of log(y) ~ log(n) + log(k):

```
Residuals:
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.4445 -0.1136 -0.0253  0.1370  0.5007 

Coefficients:
         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -16.80405    0.13749 -122.22   <2e-16 ***
log(n)        2.02321    0.01609  125.72   <2e-16 ***
log(k)        1.01216    0.01833   55.22   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1803 on 197 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9897,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9896 
F-statistic:  9428 on 2 and 197 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Here's the output of the principle components, showing both n and k are contributing to the spread of the multivariate model:

```
                      PC1(This is n)    PC2 (this is k)  PC3 (noise?)
Standard deviation     1.3654           1.0000           0.36840
Proportion of Variance 0.6214           0.3333           0.04524
Cumulative Proportion  0.6214           0.9548           1.00000
```

Comment: Using `n` and `k` as factors seems useless - it just discards the information you have about the relationship between different `n` and `k` values. As big O estimates are "up to a constant" (i.e., n, 2n, and 200n are considered equivalent), estimating a linear model of the form b1 * n + b2 * k also seems pointless. Try a log-log model (log time ~ log n + log k).

Comment: If you want to get fancy, throw in an interaction term between `log(n)` and `log(k)`.

Comment: I updated the post. log model has higher R^2. Is this what I'm looking for - the model that yields highest R^2?

Comment: You _can not_ get a big-O analysis out of measurement. You can get some hints about what the asymptotic complexity _might be_, but without knowing something about the algorithm, no finite number of measurements will be sufficient to know for sure.

Comment: And no, the highest R^2 isn't what you're looking for. R^2 for the log model and the non-log model aren't comparable. What I'm trying to help you find is a model that has a correct *functional form* for estimating big O.

Comment: The coefficient of 2 in the  log-linear model suggests the complexity is O(n^2). since `log(time) ~ const + 2*log(n)` suggests that time is proportional to  n ^ 2. Same sort of reasoning was used to infer that it takes 5 mutations to result (on average) in a cell becoming coming cancerous.

Comment: @DanielWagner, I think I see your point about BigO. What about *average case* complexity. Can you glean this via measurement? I am most interested in a relative time complexity ruling. Again, the algorithm is too chaotic for me to inspect with the eye, as there is a wrapper function and just too many lines of code.

Comment: @areyoujokingme My comment is completely independent of what statistic you are trying to get an asymptotic bound for -- worst-case runtime vs. input size, average-case runtime vs. input size, best-case runtime vs. input size, memory usage vs. input size, even "number of times the program prints `Hello, world!`" vs. "temperature in Greenwich".

Comment: @DanielWagner, I'm either not understanding you, or I disagree. Do you have a reference that would help explain your perspective?

Comment: Thank you, @42, for your input. Would k be constant, or would it be k*n^2, since it's log(time) ~ 1*log(k) + 2log(n) --> k*n^2?

Comment: @areyoujokingme In [the formal definition of big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition), the piece I'm pointing at right now is the fact that you are allowed to choose an arbitrarily large cut-off point below which the behavior of the function is ignored. In concrete terms, imagine an algorithm whose runtime is exponential in the first terabyte of input, but then linear in the remaining input -- this is still an `O(n)` runtime vs. input size algorithm.

Comment: @areyoujokingme In other words, no matter how many measurements you do, you can't be sure they haven't all been below the magic cutoff point where the function starts behaving drastically differently... *unless* you know something special about the algorithm, e.g. by inspecting its source code.

Comment: @areyoujokingme: Any process that is `O(K*n^2)` is `O(n^2)`. The O() notation is designed to capture only the functional form i.e. the maximal polynomial degree or log or exp, not any linear factors that might apply to those forms. It's designed to predict ratios under conditions of scaling, so the constant would be the same in low and high scale.